# Replace solution of NDSolve into another NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, replacement, warning-messages, finite-element-method, code-request

I was wondering if it was possible to replace the solution of `L'[x]` (which is dependent on `r[x]`, `R[x]`, and `L[x]`) of this code:

```
vL := (TL*L[x])/(km + L[x]);

km = 3.63(*3.63*);
L0 = 1(*1*);
TL = 1(*1*);

solution = NDSolve[{L'[x] == -vL, L[0] == L0}, L[x], {x, 0, 100}]
```

Into the `L'[x]` of this ODE (eqn)

```
diffCo = 1*10^-6;

bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]};

eqn=diffCo*u''[x]+(vL/.solution)==0;

solNDSolve = 
 NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}]

Plot[Evaluate[u[x] /. solNDSolve], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

When I do so, I get this error:

```
NDSolve::femper: PDE parsing error of {{u$1660063/1000000+<<1>>/(3.63 +InterpolatingFunction[{{<<2>>}},<<3>>,{Automatic}][x])}}. Inconsistent equation dimensions.
```

I also tried plugging `vL` into `eqn`, but that gave another set of errors.

**EDIT: In a more complicated situation where the NDSolveValue has 3 equations in it. Is it possible to extract just the L'[x] to plug into eqn?**

```
k1 = 0.193;
k2 = 0.7;
n = (200*^9)/(1.3*^-9);
NA = 6.02*^23;
NT = ((n/NA)*1930)*1.7;

sol = NDSolveValue[{r'[x] == (k2*R[x]) - (k1*r[x]*L[x]),
    L'[x] == (k2*R[x]) - (k1*r[x]*L[x]),
    R'[x] == (k1* r[x]*L[x]) - (k2*R[x]),
    r[0] == NT, L[0] == 1, R[0] == 0}, {r, L, R}, {x, 0, 25}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `NDSolveValue` to get the InterpolatingFunctions directly:

```
vL := (TL*L[x])/(km + L[x]);

km = 3.63(*3.63*);
L0 = 1(*1*);
TL = 1(*1*);

solution = NDSolveValue[{L'[x] == -vL, L[0] == L0}, L, {x, 0, 100}]
```

Then:

```
diffCo = 1*10^-6;
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]};
eqn = diffCo*u''[x] + (solution[x]) == 0;
solNDSolve = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}];
Plot[solNDSolve[x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

For multiple equations you can use something like:

```
{myr, myL, myR} = 
 NDSolveValue[{r'[x] == (k2*R[x]) - (k1*r[x]*L[x]), 
   L'[x] == (k2*R[x]) - (k1*r[x]*L[x]), 
   R'[x] == (k1*r[x]*L[x]) - (k2*R[x]), r[0] == NT, L[0] == 1, 
   R[0] == 0}, {r, L, R}, {x, 0, 25}]
```

Comment: how do you know when to use NDSolve and NDSolveValue?

Comment: In a situation where I have 3 equations inside the initial NDSolveValue (under EDIT) that's dependent on each other, is it possible to extract just the solution from L'[x] to replace into the second NDSolve eqn?

Comment: @BaiSango, see update.

Comment: Ohhh. So in the multiple equation case, when replacing/calling the L'[x] portion in eqn, I would say myL[x] correct?

Comment: @BaiSango, yes correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
vL := (TL*L[x])/(km + L[x]);

km = 3.63(*3.63*);
L0 = 1(*1*);
TL = 1(*1*);

Ls = NDSolveValue[{L'[x] == -vL, L[0] == L0}, L, {x, 0, 100}]
diffCo = 1*10^-6;

bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]};

eqn = diffCo*u''[x] + (TL*Ls[x])/(km + Ls[x]) == 0;

solNDSolve = 
 NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}}]

Plot[Evaluate[u[x] /. solNDSolve], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Oh. I see. 

In a similar situation where I have 3 equations inside the initial NDSolveValue (under EDIT) that's dependent on each other, is it possible to extract just the solution from L'[x] to replace into the second NDSolve eqn?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, the general model looks like  `Ls = NDSolveValue[{equations}, L, dom]`